# JSF 2.0 DataTable like component

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I need to display some tabular data in a JSF page. I need some kind of grid component, but it is a must for it to have a pager and also to be able to sort the displayed data(example: by date created, alphabetically or simmilar...)  Most probably i will start to create a custom component that fits all my needs, but i was wondering is is there any tag in JSF 2.0 or in some other library that already includes all this features. I would prefer not to use an external library like richfaces or similar just clean JSF 2.0. But if there is any good gadget out there i might give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [p:dataTable component from Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableComplex.jsf). It has sorting, filtering, pagination, row selection and a lot more features.

Getting started with Primefaces is quite simple. [Download the jar](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html), put it in your classpath and add the following namespace definition to your facelet's `html` tag:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
```